# Append into a Span by moving into the DOM (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is really specific and I'm not sure you'll enjoy it but I dont have anyone else than you who can help me so I put it there hopping someone would take the time to help me get how it's working.

Here is my problem; I've got multiple **select** (HTML one) all precede by a **span**. My question is this one : ***How can I get the value selected and put it into the span.***

I've come with something like this but i don't know why, this is always coming up with the same value :

### jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(afficheSelect);
function afficheSelect(){
    $('select').change(function() {
    $('span').append($('option').val());
    });
}
```

### HTML (Multiple select)

```
<div class="selector">
  <select>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
  </select>
  <span><span>
</div>
```

I've tough of the fonction .next() and do something like : ***$('.selector').next('span')*** but this is not going anywhere.

If anyone can help me on this I'll be fairly grateful !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
$(function(){
$('.selector select').on('keyup change', function(e) {
    $(this).next('span').html($(this).find(":selected").text());
});
});
```

This way you can have multiple select in a page

Comment: Beautiful ! 
I've used a mix of your's and mine and it worked perfectly !

Comment: $('select').change(function() {
                    $(this).next('span').append($(this).val());
                });

Comment: Using "keyup" will manage the keyboard events also. using "on" will handle the ajax appended elements to work. So its better to use the script I gave.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function() {
        $('span').append($(this).val());
    });
})
```

Comment: 'Right... I was close :(

Thank you !

Comment: @Baldráni Use proper name/id/class for elements in order for it to work.

Comment: If prefiere to avoid it as much as possible i've got allready a hugissim load of class and id for the back gestion :)